# LOCKSCREEN timeout - not SCREENTIMEOUT

Tags: android, lockscreen

I have seen so many questions about Screen Time out and I know how to change the screen timeout.

But I'd like to change the time that display will remain active in lockscreen mode. My question is how to change the time that display remains active when device is locked.
Is there anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Before KitKat (4.4), the normal screen timeout setting (Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT) would also work on the lockscreen. Since KitKat that no longer works (defaults to 10s), EXCEPT for activities displayed ABOVE the lockscreen, such as an incoming call. I would also like to know how to programmatically change the timeout while on the lockscreen on KK+.